# How do I sync my music library from my iPhone to my MacBook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, data-synchronization

I just purchased a MacBook Air and I'm trying to sync my music library from my iPhone 6 to the new Macbook and only music purchased from the iTunes Store shows up on the MacBook although I have lots of other albums on my phone?

Comment: How did you get the non-iTunes Store-purchased music onto the iPhone in the first place?

Comment: In the past, I've used http://www.findleydesigns.com/ipodaccess/. It allows you to export the music in your iPhone, from there, you could manually add it back to the iTunes library. (Not 100% sure if it supports IOS8, or the newest version of OSX, but worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

iTunes does not sync non-purchased music (or movies or tv shows) from a device back to the computer. You will need third-party software on the computer, such as [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer), to complete this.

(I swear there was another question like this that has been answered before, but I couldn't find it.)